# Задача на JS "Генератор массива"

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать генератор массивов длиной count со случайными числами от n до m с учётом, что n и m могут быть отрицательными, а также может быть n > m или n < m. Нужно использовать в коде конструктор new Array(n) для создания массива длины n.

```
let a = [];
let m = 0;
let n = 100;
let count = 100;

for ( let i = m; i < count; ++i ) {
    a.push( Math.round(Math.random() * n) );
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const createArray = (s, n, m) => Array.from({ length: s }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.max(n, m) - Math.min(n, m) + 1)) + Math.min(n, m));

console.log(createArray(3, 1, 5));
console.log(createArray(3, 5, 1));
console.log(createArray(3, 5, -5));
```

Comment: Таак. Что за минусы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
let count = 42;
let n = -3;
let m = -10;
a = [];
let max = Math.max(n,m);
let min = Math.min(n,m);
for (let i = 0 ; i < count; i ++){
    a.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: `+ min)` -> `) + min`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
let n = 20;
let m = -10;
let count = 5;
let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
array.push(Math.round(Math.random() * Math.abs(n - m)) + Math.min(m, n));
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]